# Form css reflecting to ajax calendar  css

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

I am using MS AJAX ASP.NET Component (Calendar Extender) and i used some css properties for form divs its reflecting to calendar divs, how can apply default css for calendar extender, and i can't remove my css styles for the form. 
The css code is

```
#form div{min-width:100px; float:left;}
```

Comment: can you do a more specific selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1) add another textbox to the page, outside the updatepanel your calendar extender is in

2) add a calendar extender and point at the textbox

3) on the textbox set 'style="display:none;" so it doesnt' show up on the page.